# Iphone web application problem on iphone keyboard open

Tags: iphone, keyboard

I have a problem of layout in view my website on iphone/Ipad, when the iphone keyboard open The whole website moved to top due to which user will not be able to view the top content while the keyboard is open. When keyboard is close the website will be back to its original position.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the below nottification methods in init method of the controller showing your website:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                      selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                      name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];


[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                      selector:@selector(keyboardWasHidden:)
                                      name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification object:nil];
```

try setting the frame of your website in the corresponding notification methods (keyboardWasShown,keyboardWasHidden). Eg:- Say your webSiteView is the view disaplying your website and x,y are the coordinates of the view when keyboard is not visible. When the keyBoard is shown, set the frame of the webSiteView with the new x1 and y1 coordinates that will show the view the way you want.

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown: (id)sender {
    [webSiteView setFrame:CGRectMake(x1,y1,w,h)];
}

- (void)keyboardWasHidden: (id)sender {
    [webSiteView setFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,w,h)];
}
```

Also if you are not able to see the entire webSite, try adding your webSiteView into a scrollView and set the frame of the ScrollView in the notification methods.